# Dropbox DropNet Delta API Sample

Tags: dropbox, delta, dropnet

I am looking for to sync up operation with my client app folders should always be updated with with server files and folders.. maybe Delta will help me in this case

I am looking for some sample source code to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Look at longpoll_delta request at last version of DropNet. It has sync and async realizations and can watch files and folders updating.
The usage is similar to official API for DropBox: [longpoll_delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#longpoll-delta).